# Convergent/Divergent test: $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty e^{2n} \cos(\pi n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Trying to figure out if I use the alternating series test or divergence test.

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty e^{2n} \cos(\pi n)$$

I believe $\cos$ will be between $-1$ and $1$ and while  $$n \to \infty $$
$$e^{2n} \to \infty$$
Does this mean it is divergent and I should use test for divergence ?

Comment: Do the terms go to $0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest test or first check, based on the negation of:
$$\sum a_n \; \mbox{converges} \implies a_n \to 0$$
yields (for *any* series, not necessarily alternating):
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \ne 0 \implies  \sum a_n \; \mbox{diverges}$$
Now note that $e^{2n} \cos(\pi n) \not\to 0$.